# How to create joins with multiple many to many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to show the revenue that each restaurant has generated, however, I am struggling to figure out how to do this as a result of the tables created by the many-to-many relationships. I know that I will need to do a number of joins but I am not too sure how to start.

```
select rest_name, (menuItems_qty * menuItem_Price) as TotalEarnings
from restaurant, Menu, orders_has_menu
where
group by rest_name
order by TotalEarnings desc
```

image: [`here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfG2m.png)

Comment: eye's aren't up for squinting at ER diagrams, so hint: "FROM restaurant JOIN menu ON restaurant.{field} = Menu.{field} JOIN orders_has_menu ON Menu.{field} = orders_has_menu.{field} ...` fill out field to match criteria that joins the tables.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server - pick the one you are actually using, tag correctly!

Comment: Start by using explicit joins rather than comma joins and build your query from simple heading towards complex.

Comment: I suggest you learn sql starting with a well-designed schema. Yours is very flawed and you can't nor won't learn good habits starting with a flawed schema. First step is to learn how to join tables.There are many tutorials covering that - what we shouldn't do is use the old and very error prone [join via where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Do you have any comments on what part of my schema is flawed?/where to improve it?

Comment: @canada123 - did you attempt danblack's hint in first comment? Please make an effort as `JOIN` is simple basic SQL querying.